# Google Contacts API - issue in getting birthday

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, google-api, google-contacts-api

Am able to get google contacts from https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full

but not the birthday.

What should i do to get the birthday, do i need to provide any special permission or any other query url ?

Please help...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I have been using the Google data provider and believe it’s the easiest way to achieve the behavior you are looking for. It’s basically a third party tool that allows to connect and access data just as you would access any traditional database. After having configured it, selecting the birthday is as simple as querying the Contacts table:

```
GoogleConnection connection = new GoogleConnection(connectionString);

GoogleCommand cmd = new GoogleCommand(
    "SELECT Birthday FROM Contacts where Contacts.Birthday >= @date", 
    connection);
cmd.Parameters.Add(new GoogleParameter("date", "4/3/1997"));

GoogleDataReader gdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (gdr.Read())
{
    //any code
}
```

I’ve found this a lot easier than other methods. This is the link to their site: [Google Data Provider](http://www.rssbus.com/ado/google/)

Comment: Both your answers so far ultimately link to rssbus.com. Do you have any affiliation with this company? If you, according to the faq you have to mention this in your answers.